# vertically align right aligned navbar items within grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to create a navbar using the CSS `grid` attribute. Currently I have this

```css
#navbar {
  height: 60px;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: right;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}

#navbarLinkContainer {}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="navbarLinkContainer">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
    <a href="/projects">Projects</a>
    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="/imprint">Imprint</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my problem is that I don't know how to center the links vertically within the `navbarLinkContainer`.

I tried to add `align-items: center` and `vertical-align: middle` to the `navbarLinkContainer` but this didn't help. So how can I center the links within the navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `align-items: center` on the `#navbar` instead; since it is a flex-container it will align its children at the middle; also changed your `justify-items: right` to `justify-content: end`

```css
#navbar {
  height: 60px;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: end;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
  align-items: center;
}

#navbarLinkContainer {}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="navbarLinkContainer">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
    <a href="/projects">Projects</a>
    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="/imprint">Imprint</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add `align-items: center` to your `#navbar`:

```css
#navbar {
  height: 60px;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: right;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}

#navbarLinkContainer {}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="navbarLinkContainer">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
    <a href="/projects">Projects</a>
    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="/imprint">Imprint</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want all the links to be in the center, you could modify "justify-items: center;" in the navbar

```
#navbar {
  height: 60px;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}

#navbarLinkContainer {}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}


<div id="navbar">
  <div id="navbarLinkContainer">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
    <a href="/projects">Projects</a>
    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="/imprint">Imprint</a>
  </div>
</div>
```